# Sorting specific rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

Data:-

```
df:-

    Name       Date
1    A     2015-01-01
2    B     2016-05-01
3    B     2015-01-05
4    A     2015-12-25
5    C     2015-01-01
```

Code:-

```
df <- df[order(df[,c("Name")]),]
> df
  Name       Date
1    A 2015-01-01
4    A 2015-12-25
2    B 2016-05-01
3    B 2015-01-05
5    C 2015-01-01
index= which(df$Name=="B")
start= index[1]
end=index[length(index)]
df[start:end,] <- df[order(df[start:end,("Date")]),]

> df
   Name       Date
1    A    2015-01-01
4    A    2015-12-25
2    A    2015-12-25
3    A    2015-01-01
5    C    2015-01-01
```

As one can see this is not the output I was expecting. I sort the dataframe first by **Name**,which works well and then I try to sort the individual rows of specific names. I find the starting and ending index of a particular name and try to sort the specific rows by **Date**. Second sorting leads to this error output. Please advice , also is there any shorter method for this? Thanks in advance.

Expected Output:-

```
Name       Date
1    A 2015-01-01
4    A 2015-12-25
3    B 2015-01-05 
2    B 2016-05-01
5    C 2015-01-01
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @mtoto I am trying to sort all the rows having their names as "B" by Date

Comment: @Jain I think you have a typo in your post, you have `dd[order(df[,c("Name")]),]` but I think you want `dd` to be `df`.

Comment: @steveb Thank for pointing that out, I changed that.

Comment: @Jain You may want to include the expected output, as that should make it a bit more clear.

Comment: I love this: "As one can see this is not the output I was expecting." ... Because of course we should know exactly what you wanted to do given your incomplete explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you do not yet understand that `order` can take both primary and secondary sort vectors:

```
> df1 <- read.table(text="    Name       Date
+ 1    A     2015-01-01
+ 2    B     2016-05-01
+ 3    B     2015-01-05
+ 4    A     2015-12-25
+ 5    C     2015-01-01", head=TRUE)
> df1[ order(df1$Name, df1$Date) , ]
  Name       Date
1    A 2015-01-01
4    A 2015-12-25
3    B 2015-01-05
2    B 2016-05-01
5    C 2015-01-01
```

Comment: ... and tertiary, etc

Comment: I did think about adding tertiary ,even quaterneray or higher "-ary"s were possible, ..., and probably should have advised reading the help page where the Usage section would have shown that an arbitrary number of vectors were possible as indicated by the initial argument being the triple-dots.

Comment: [more ary's](http://giphy.com/gifs/cowbell-snl-saturday-night-live-nUAuTPG3BqFC8)